# Scala akka : implement abstract class with subtype parameter

Tags: scala, inheritance, abstract

I have a problem with my design. I just want to do this but I cannot achieve it. Compilator complains about the process method not implemented in MyProcessor so MyProcessor should be abstract...

```
trait Event 

abstract class EventProcessor extends Actor{
    def receive ={
        case evt : Event => process(evt)
        case evts : Iterable[Event] => process(evts)
    }

    def process(event :Event): Iterable[SomeObject]

    def process(events :Iterable[Event])={
      events.flatMap(process)
    }
}

case class MyEvent extends Event

class MyProcessor extends Processor{
    def process(event :MyEvent)={
      some processing...
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure it's a well known pattern. What is your method ?

I need 2 things :

- How to correctly implement subclass with type parameter (as decribe in first answer ?)
- How to go through type erasure ?

EDIT : solution

```
trait Event 

abstract class EventProcessor[T<:Event:ClassTag] extends Actor{

    def receive ={
        case evt : T=> process(evt)
        case evts : Iterable[T] => process(evts)
    }

    def process(event :T): Iterable[SomeObject]

    def process(events :Iterable[T])={
      events.flatMap(process)
    }
}

case class MyEvent extends Event

class MyProcessor extends Processor[MyEvent]{
    def process(event :MyEvent)={
      some processing...
    }
}
```

Comment: There is indeed a problem in your design. You say an EventProcessor can process any kind of event, but MyProcessor can only process MyEvent. You cannot have a supertype promise something and then make a subtype that breaks the promise. You need to either restrict the original supertype contract, ir expand the subtype contract, such that the latter covers the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a type parameter:

```
abstract class EventProcessor[T <: Event] {
  def process(event: T)
}
class MyProcessor extends  Processor[MyEvent] {
  def process(event: MyEvent)
}
```

Comment: Sorry I went to quickly on the code simplification. I updated my question... but thanks for your answer

Comment: I don't see much new in the edited version. The same answer applies: replace all occurrences of `Event` with `T`   in the superclass.

Comment: the difference is in the pattern matching but I think I need ClassTag